# This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Tags: php, wordpress, networking

I am getting a very strange error which I have no idea what is going on or how to fix.  The strange thing is that I can connect to the /admin on my wordpress site. As soon as I try and view the site it crashes and I get this message - Any Ideas?

I have just downloaded a new copy of wordpress from the website.  I go into php my admin create a database and username and password and matching what it is in wp-config file.

I then expect to login to localhost 8887 but as as soon as I hit that route I get to that site the port number disappears and I get this error message.

I have been experimenting with ssh tunneling this week so worried I have may have messed up some config but not really sure where to begin ?  I dont think it is a wordpress problem more a networking problem?

[image]

Comment: Post the code.. it seems that there is something wrong with paths you are seeting

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to create good questions. You shouldn't post an answer to your question unless you actually have the answer, instead edit you post to add more details.

Comment: Please provide more information so we can help you - which web server are you running? Are you _sure_ your admin site is running on the same server? Have you left out the port number on your main site URL?

Answer (score 1):

In the picture localhost is written with double L-s. Isn't that the problem?
http:// loca**ll**host..